# Should mapDispatchToProps dispatch initialization actions?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

Suppose a stateless, functional `UserProfile` component that displays user data for the given url. Suppose it is being wrapped with `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserProfile)`. Finally, suppose a reducer that reduces into `state.userProfile`. Anytime the url changes, I need to re-initialize the `state.userProfile`, so a solution that comes to mind is to do so from within the mapDispatchToProps like so:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, ownProps) {
  dispatch(fetchUser(ownProps.userId))
  return {
    ...
  }
}
```

Provided that the thunked fetchUser ignores repeated calls by comparing with current state, is this an acceptable practice? Or are there problems associated with calling dispatch immediately from this map function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unsupported and can break at any time.
`mapDispatchToProps` itself should not have side effects.

If you need to dispatch actions in response to prop changes, you can create a component class and use lifecycle methods for this:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser(this.props.id)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      this.props.fetchUser(this.props.id)
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```

Comment: Technically it is still a pure function, as far I understand, but thinking more about it I can imagine circular dispatch situations. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: If it calls `dispatch`, it isn’t pure—that’s a side effect.

Comment: I suppose it's an question of terminology, but if you go by wikipedia's definition, a pure function "always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s)." Perhaps there's another definition that you have in mind.

Comment: From Wikipedia: “Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect”. Dispatching is a side effect because it changes the global (atomically mutable) state of the app.

Comment: For example, `alert()` or `xhr.send()` are not pure even though they return the same value (`undefined`) on every call.

Comment: alert modifies the ui state, and xhr modifies the state of the network. dispatch is just a parameter. But you are still correct, if you take to the "semantic" definition. Semantically we expect dispatch to be a specific function, even though it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Another reason not to dispatch in `mapDispatchToProps` is that you now coupled your component to redux entirely and made it impossible to run unit tests on. If you were to test the non-connected component, it would be missing the bit of logic about mounting and unmounting.

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative. I appreciate very much the input, but this has been something that I keep coming back to in my code. In my unit tests I don't want to test _that_ "bit of logic". I want the stateless component to be agnostic of where it's getting its data from. I almost wish for a third map function that exposes the lifecycle events from the `connect`'s internal component.

Comment: Well in those cases you should be making a container component that can do the fetch, and then have a presentational component that's not connected at all. Then it's easy to unit test without that bit of logic since the container is the only one containing it. So just ignore it.