# How to fetch initial data with react-redux connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm reading the doc here https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

I'd like to use Stateless component as much as possible, but I cannot figure out how I'd go about the initial data payload. With a Stateful React component, My container and component would look:

```
// Container
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchDataAction());
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);

// Component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }
}
```

Where does the logic of `componentDidMount` go if I make my component stateless?

I've seen examples, where they suggest you extend your stateless component in your container with stateful React, and add that logic there:

```
// Container
class MyComponentContainer extends MyComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData();
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponentContainer);
```

But is that a best way to do it? If I am bothering to create a Stateful React, why not just do it directly on `MyComponent`?

**EDIT** Just to be clear; I'm asking if I can basically load my initial data WITHOUT ever creating a `React.Component` anywhere.

Comment: Why not call fetchData on the componentDidMount for the container component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related your main question: yes, it's totally possible to load data as soon as your `store` is created. Just use `store.dispatch` from any place in your code even outside `React.Components`.

You can check a [simple example here](https://jsbin.com/visihig/edit?html,js,output). As you can see Components and data loading process are totaly separated from each other in it.

> But is that a best way to do it? If I am bothering to create a Stateful React, why not just do it directly on MyComponent?

Indeed I don't see any reason to do anything like what you provided in the snippet. Even more, inheriting your Components from anything else than `React.Component` is definitely a smell in React world.

Answer (score 0):

you can dispatch an action in mapDispatchToProps but it is a dirty way and not at all recommended.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) {
    dispatch(fetchDataAction());
    return {
    }
}
```

But now mapDispatchToProps will not be pure as that's a side effect.
Correct solution is to have a container component which will be stateful React Component and on Mount dispatch the action.

Another solution can be if you are using `react-redux-router` then:

- dispatch action onEnter - https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux/issues/319
- dispatch action everytime route changes - https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/227

Refer this: [Should mapDispatchToProps dispatch initialization actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654197/should-mapdispatchtoprops-dispatch-initialization-actions)

**Eidt:** similar question [How to dispatch Redux action from stateless component when route is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39761443/how-to-dispatch-redux-action-from-stateless-component-when-route-is-loaded)